# REST API Schema

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I'm developing rest web services with spring mvc, and everything is stright forward, but I've faced with one problem how to expose the api schema for the consumers something like wsdl.I want to have one web page with all methods(end points e.q. request mapping) and what kind of request method(GET, POST), and expected request params type(json, xml, post params, get params).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fantastic way to show this is with the [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) tool. Swagger will let you create an html test harness that shows expected params, makes demo requests and shows the API responses.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. There seems to be a Maven plugin also on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Application Description Language (`WADL`) is an XML vocabulary used to describe RESTful web services.

As with WSDL, a generic client can load a WADL file and be immediately equipped to access the full functionality of the corresponding web service.

Since RESTful services have simpler interfaces, WADL is not nearly as necessary to these services as WSDL is to RPC-style SOAP services.